# Creating a custom JSON response object with Zend Action Helper ContextSwitch

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, helper, context-switch

I normally append an encoded json object to the response body, however I now have a situation that warrants using the ContextSwitch action helper.

I have a Zend_Form that requires three different response contexts:

1. **html** - Render the form as normal html
   within a layout.
2. **html-partial** - An ajax "get" request that renders
   just the form as html.
3. **json** - An ajax "post" request that returns
   any form valiation error messages.

For each context I have 3 view scripts. Although the two html contexts could use the same view script, but I haven't figured out if this is possible.

- **form.phtml**
- **form.html.phtml**
- form.json.phtml

The html context views work okay, but the json view is not being picked up. What is the best method to override the default json post callback behaviour or pass a custom encoded object to the response body?

Comment: I have discovered that setting setAutoJsonSerialization(false) on the contextSwitch allows for a view script to be rendered, while still keeping the context Content-Type header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I don't use "View" to generate JSON content.
In my `init()`, I have something like this:

```
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$ajaxContext->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)
    ->addActionContext('index', array('html', 'json'))
    ->initContext();
```

And In my `indexAction()`:

```
if ( true === $this->isAjaxJson() ) {
    $this->_helper->json(
        array(
            'response' => $myResponse,
            'message' => $myMesage
        )
    );
    return;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes that is more or less how I did it. However I use used a separate view script to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

this may help :
`$this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);`
while,

`$data=array('data1'=>'val1','data2'=>'val2');`