# Zend response application/json utf-8

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

usually in a xhr action I use  this code

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json', true);
return $response->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($data));
```

I'm wondering if it need utf-8 encoding like this

```
$response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', true);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be good practice to do so. You may not see any problems if you don't. It depends what kind of data you are sending.

there is a much shorter way to do what you are doing (Disables layouts and sets the right headers):

```
 $this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);
```

Comment: in view/helper I only see $response = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);
        return $data; so .....

Comment: It seems like `sendJson` does not set allow you to set a specific charset (e.g. utf-8).

Comment: Looking at `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json` I can't see anything about headers 'application/json;charset=UTF-9'.

Answer (score 3):

You should better use [contextswitch/ajaxcontext helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch). See example in first answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231584/creating-a-custom-json-response-object-with-zend-action-helper-contextswitch).