# Zend response setBody duplicates my data

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I have a RESTful Zend action which should send me back a json encoded object, but in the response whatever I set in the body gets duplicated.

My code looks like this :

```
    public function blablaAction() {
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
      $response = $this->getResponse();
      [...]
      $response->setBody('aaaaaaaa' . json_encode($output) . 'aaaaaaaa');
      $response->sendResponse();
    }
```

And if I look at the response body, I can see:

```
      aaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXaaaaaaaa
```

(`XXXXXXXXXXXXXX` being the json encoded data).

Why?

PS: I added the `aaaaaaa` just to make sure the problem didn't come from the json encoding. I'll just have `$response->setBody(json_encode($output));` when it finally works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround from this question: [Zend response application/json utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445843/zend-response-application-json-utf-8)

It works as expected if, instead of using `$response` along with `setBody`, I use `$this->_helper->json->sendJson($output);`.

This is only a workaround and would like to understand what's the problem with `setBody`, so I won't accept this "answer"...